# How is this actually done?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local, passport-google-oauth

I am doing a project with authentication using passport js with the Strategies (Google, Facebook, Local). I am working on the google part now but there is a small problem. When users register locally I save their data to the db (email,username,hashedPassword) but now when they register/signin through google I do not have access to their password (obviously). It is required in the user schema and I do not want to create a new user schema.

Could I save the password as the user id I received from google? I really want to know the correct path I should take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add another field to your schema like `provider` that specifies the type of authentication that was used. Then you can use the [mongoose required validator](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators) to make password only required if provider is 'local.' Something like this:

```js
const userSchema= new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String,
  username: String,
  provider: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['local', 'google', 'facebook']
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: function() {
      return this.provider === 'local';
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you go use an auth provider, they usually will give you some sort of "token", maybe on your client or on a redirect on your server (depends on your implementation).

Then you have to validate that token with the provider (how to do this depends on the documentation of each provider), because you can not plain trust that a given token is valid.

Once you have validated with the provider that the token is valid, is common that with that token you have access to some info of the user, like email, name, phone number, etc (depends on how you configure your integration) and maybe store which provider they use (fb, google, apple, etc)

Then you can save this information in your schema, and then generate a session for this user (it may be a JWT or a session stored on the db)

Now, when a user sign in, you will do the same validation process of the given token with the user sent, then you can provide a new session

In summary, the key is that instead of using user/pwd to validate against your local database to authenticate a user, they will provide a token, and you have to validate that token against the provider they selected